# Цвет шапки приложения

Tags: android, android-studio

Как изменить цвет шапки приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можно изменить тему приложения. В соседнем ответе рассказали, как это сделать кодом, покажу, как это сделать через описание темы. Если не ошибаюсь, профит этого способа в том, что вы не увидите на экране цвет по умолчанию, если по какой-то причине загрузка приложения длилась долго.

Итак, в `res/values/themes.xml` нужно переопределить тему для action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        …
```

И в ней определить цвет:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Если имеется в виду **ActionBar**, то делаете так:

1) Передаём гуглу строку

> https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20action%20bar%20color%20programmatically

2) Идём по первой ссылке и находим ответ такой:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.red));
```

3) Можно и иначе. Задать свой собственный **View** **ActionBar**-у; Или поменять цвет в стилях.

Comment: Я не нашел, как задавать стиль.

Comment: @Vlmake, а первый вариант чем не устраивает?